Aggregated Link with Wi-Fi and Ethernet
I hope I'm in the right place to ask this question.
For context: I recently moved in an appartment, and back in my old home I had fiber (1Gb+), in this new appartment, I installed a Starlink because I wanted to get more speed and a closer experience to my old connection. Of course, it's not the same but I'm getting some decent numbers.
Anyway, now, the thing is, whenever the Starlink Antenna, bounces from one satellite to another, I get a ping spike and sometimes I even get disconnected from my game.
To avoid that, my idea was to also connect my computer in wifi to my ISP, so that even if it's slow I'm always connected to internet.
So to achieve that, I tried to change the priority in my Windows Control Panel. I put the Starlink connection (Ethernet) on Metric 1 and the ISP connection (Wi-Fi) on Metric 10.
This way whenever the Starlink goes "down" it switches to the ISP, and then back to the Starlink. But by doing that, I can feel my speeds clearly arent as quick as they could be, and also by doing speedtests, it doesn't seem like it's taking the right network.
Maybe I have some configurations issues, but I don't know if windows is capable of having this kind of failover support...
I still feel a slight ping spike when playing so I was wondering if you guys had any idea on how I could potentially solve this thing, thanks!
I also tried to use speedify, but for some reasons all of my games are blocked when I use it.

“To avoid that, my idea was to also connect my computer in wifi to my ISP, so that even if it's slow I'm always connected to internet.” - Your ISP is Starlink, and Starlink itself, is having those lag spikes. So your idea won’t prevent those lag spikes. If you actually have two ISP services then what you want would be possible but the hardware to do it definitely isn’t cheap.

From your description, it sounds like it may be using only one network (as route failover using just interface metrics doesn't quite work that way). Have you checked which network is being used in reality, e.g. by looking at the network graphs in Task Manager?

Maybe I should add some clarification,
For @Ramhound I actually have 2 ISPs, Starlink and a standard ISP in this case Swisscom. I understand that this might be tricky to do but still I'm okay to try and give it a shot.

For @grawity_u1686 I guess it's probably what's happening. I found the interface metrics as a solution on google, so it's clear it wouldn't work right away. Hence why I'm here. As for which network is being used, I'm not exactly sure how I can tell from the task manager, because both interface seem to be doing something, but by telling from a speedtest it's not working the way I intended it to. And yes I wish to have some sort of failover for when the starlink bounces from one satellite to another.

There are WiFi routers that have multiple WAN. Using such a router would probably be the best option to do this cheaply. A huge YouTuber based out of Canada on one of this alternative channels has a router review that recently in the last 48 hours was posted . Hardware recommendation are out of scope so I am being specific enough without saying who that Canadian YouTuber is exactly. They sell a screwdriver, backpacks, and other stuff.

You can't switch an existing TCP connection or a UDP flow from one ISP to another. TCP connections and UDP flows are defined by the 4-tuple (source IP address, source port, destination IP address, destination port). Your connection to the Internet via one ISP is going to go through a NAT gateway and be rewritten to have a source IP address registered to that ISP. If you tried, in the middle of the TCP connection or UDP flow, to start sending the packets through a different ISP, they would have to be rewritten to have a source IP address registered to the other ISP, which would make them part of a separate connection by definition, and those packets would be ignored by the game server.
So you'd still lose your connection to the game server.
You can load balance between two ISP connections, or do hot failover between two ISP connections, by controlling which ISP to use when establishing a new TCP connection or UDP flow. But you can't salvage an existing TCP connection or UDP flow that started out on one ISP that is failing, by switching it over to another ISP. It just doesn't work mid-flow.
There IS a technology called "Multipath TCP" (MPTCP) that adds a layer of complexity that allows a single TCP connection to have multiple source or destination IP addresses. Apple has been a pioneer of this in order to make iPhone handoff between Wi-Fi and cell data more seamless. You could conceivably create an MPTCP-capable VPN client on your home network and an MPTCP-capable VPN server out on the public Internet (maybe via some kind of hosting provider), and have your gaming traffic go through that MPTCP-enhanced VPN tunnel, so that when Starlink hiccups, your MPTCP-enhanced VPN tunnel automagically switches ISPs. But I haven't worked with those pieces enough to know how much work that would take.


I put the Starlink connection (Ethernet) on Metric 1 and the ISP connection (Wi-Fi) on Metric 10.
This way whenever the Starlink goes "down" it switches to the ISP, and then back to the Starlink.

It doesn't work that way, as your routes in Windows don't know anything about Starlink and about whether it's up or down – all they know is whether the local Ethernet connection to your Starlink router is up or not, but not anything beyond the router.
So even if your primary ISP is down, the route with the lowest metric will continue to be used as long as your local router is still up and connected.
(Windows does have some form of checking whether an interface has Internet access, but since that involves making real HTTP requests to a real Internet server, it's only done every few minutes; definitely not something that can provide a sub-millisecond reaction.)

I still feel a slight ping spike when playing

You're not going to be able to avoid that.

For the system to fail over to a backup connection, it needs to know that the primary connection is down. And with a packet-based wireless link, there isn't necessarily a continuous carrier signal whose loss could be noticed – often the only way to know that the radio link is down is by noticing that packets aren't being received for a certain amount of time.
Meaning, there will unavoidably be a slight "ping spike" because that's what tells the system that it needs to switch to the backup connection.
Though even if there were a continuous signal, you couldn't rely on it much either as a wireless link isn't strictly on-or-off but gradually varies in reliability; e.g. interference might cause packets to be corrupted even though the link is, technically, still up.
So another measure of link loss is "too many packets damaged in transit" – which again needs to be measured over a certain amount of time. Wireless systems are inherently unreliable, so they don't want to rush to declare a link as down just because it has lost one or two packets; they will be retransmitted a few times until they get through (or not).
In case of interference, most likely your game will already have kicked you off long ago by the time the Starlink hardware decides that the connection is down.

As Spiff has already mentioned, even if the route-based failover did work, it wouldn't have the effect you want, because your two ISPs provide you with different external IP addresses and most protocols do not support having a connection moved from one address to another.
That is, even if the failover were instant, the very act of switching to a different ISP would disconnect you.
The only cheap way to avoid that would involve setting up a VPN tunnel through some external system (e.g. a VPS) with its own public IP address – either a tunnel type that inherently supports roaming (WireGuard) or two tunnels with something extra to switch between them (I've used OSPF+BFD for that purpose).


